# How to pass data to a WebApi Controller from a console application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Using this code I am not able to post data to an api (asp.net MVC latest version).
What could be the problem?
Should I set specific headers?

```
   Using client As New Net.WebClient
        Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
        reqparm.Add("DeviceId", "devicetest")
        reqparm.Add("Message", "messagetest")
        Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues("http://xxx.xxx.com/api/notification", "POST", reqparm)
        Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)
    End Using
```

Comment: How does the receiving end looks like? The action in the WebApi controller.

Comment: I found out the problem was not connected with the api. Thanks for your comment +1